# Alternatives to HTTP chunking for persistent connections?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

According to the [W3C specification on Server-Sent Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/):

> Authors are also cautioned that HTTP chunking can have unexpected negative effects on the reliability of this protocol. Where possible, chunking should be disabled for serving event streams unless the rate of messages is high enough for this not to matter.

How exactly would I go about doing this server-side in node.js? Setting the `Content-Length` header isn't really an option because the connection should ideally never close. Would I set the response header `Transfer-Encoding` to `identity` or remove the `Transfer-Encoding` header entirely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node will use `chunked` encoding automatically if you don't explicitly provide a length or manually set a transfer encoding. It would also be good to set `Connection: close` too  as you obviously won't be keeping the connection open after when the server finishes sending events.

```
res.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'identity');
res.setHeader('Connection', 'close');
```

Comment: But the connection has to stay open indefinitely and setting the `Connection` header to `close` will close the connection immediately.

Comment: @MatthewDean `Connection: close` tells the browser that the socket will close after all of the data has been sent, which is exactly what will happen. It doesn't mean it will close immediately. It will remain open until the server calls `res.end()`. If you don't explicitly provide a length, or use transfer encoding, the only way for the browser to know that there will be no more data from the server is for the connection to close.

Comment: Ah. On an unrelated note, do you have any idea why chunked encoding would be less reliable for Server-Sent Events?